# Is the sum of the given sequence a differentiable function on (0, $\infty$)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the sum of the given sequence a differentiable function on (0, $\infty$)?

S(x) = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (\frac{x}{n}-(1+\frac{x}{n})\ln(1+\frac{x}{n}))$

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n'(x)=-\frac {1}{n}\ln (1+\frac {x}{n}) $$

$$=-\frac{x}{n^2}\frac {1}{1+\frac {c}{n}} $$
by MVT.

For $a>0$,

At $[0,a] $,
$$|f_n'(x)|\leq \frac {a}{n^2} $$

the series $\sum f_n'$ is normally convergent at $[0,a ] $.
you can continue.